# No-IP, Apache: Can't load page from the server that hosts it

Tags: router, dns, apache-http-server, dynamic-dns

I have a domain name registered at No-IP, and in my server I run Apache2 and a site made with python and flask. Also, I have my router configured to forward the port of interest.

When I try to access the site from outside or from a computer in my network except for the server, I can load that page. However, every time I try to load the same page from the server where the page is, or when I try to ping my domain name from the server, the requests time out.

When I run `nslookup` with my domain name, it returns my public IP, even in the server...

What is it happening? How can I tackle this problem?

The server has Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you access to the page from the server using its local IP address ?

Comment: @S.Brottes Yes!

Comment: Are you under a NATed network ? Could you give information about the router (Model) ?

Comment: how good a router do you have? does it support NAT Hairpinning (also called Nat Loopback or Reflective Nat)? when you connect to the site from another computer inside your LAN, are you using a fully qualified domain name, or a hostname? do you have an internal DNS server for your LAN? Most SOHO grade routers do not support hairpinning, so systems inside the LAN cannot connect to the server by public IP.  they have to use a LAN IP.

Comment: also, on your server what search domains do you have set for DNS? is it the same as the other computers on the network?

Comment: I have a router GL-AR750 behind my ISP router (some commercial one). Computers connected directly to my ISP router can get pages from server (behind GL-AR750), but computers in the GL-AR750 subnet can't. GL-AR750 is connected NOT in bridge...